# Change instance variable value from external class?

Tags: java, oop

Is this possible? For example I have an object of the class enterprise called telef, which has a price variable, and I want to be able to acces that price variable of that enterprise from another class.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want read access? Or write access? What is 'access' to you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a public getter method.

For example in your enterprise class:

```
private String price;

public String getPrice() 
{
        return price;
}
```

Now from any other class that has the object `telef` we can write:

```
String price = telef.getPrice();
```

Comment: Could I have an example?I will use the instance in 3+ classes

Comment: What if the class doesnt have the object and the object is declared on another class?

Comment: Then you'll likely want to give the object to this other class.  Perhaps pass it in the constructor or as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is against the data hiding concept but you can do it by making it public simply..

Comment: The problem comes when I use telef.price (being public) or telef.getPrice, it doesnt recognise telef.

Comment: I fixed it, I have 4 classes, player, enemy, main and enterprise. I was instantiating an enterprise object on main, and then setting up a buy function on player, and using enterprise.telef instead of main.telef